# Fatal Error: Call to undefined function in a drush backup module

Tags: drush, xml-sitemap

I am getting a weird error when attempting to use Drush.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `variable_get()` in
>   /home/1000/.drush/backups/pantheon/20161102190143/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.drush.inc on line 29
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   Error: Call to undefined function `variable_get()` in /home/1000/.drush/backups/pantheon/20161102190143/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.drush.inc, line 29

I have disabled and removed the xmlsitemap module, but it looks like it is referencing some weird backup version of the module.

Comment: How about clear site and drush cache? Can it fix?

Answer (score 1):

The function `variable_get` doesn't exist in Drupal 8. I suggest just removing `~/.drush/backups/pantheon/20161102190143/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.drush.inc` or moving `~/.drush/backups` to `~/.drushbackups` if you can control this.

Your problem is probably caused by the fact that you are putting the backup inside the `~/.drush` directory and Drush is parsing code/files in that directory.

Comment: Thanks - I'm using 7 but it seems to have worked itself out when creating a new instance based off of my most recent commit to a dev server.

Comment: OK, so I missed about your version of Drupal (that is why you should include as much info as possible when asking a question), but I'm 100% correct about the cause of the problem. I just download the xmlsitemap module into my .drush folder and, pang, I got the "undefined function variable_get()" (under Drupal 7 and an old Drush). I guess Drush is parsing the files in .drush folder before it bootstraps Drupal.